# Get Application Name From Keyboard Input in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am making application in vb.net which when ran detects keystrokes from keyboard in any editors. Now I can get keystrokes, thats easy part but I want to know the application name like if user is writing in notepad, then I want that name.
Please can any one suggest any idea.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use windows api:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim shortName as String = GetShortEXEName(GetForegroundWindow() ) 
End Sub

' Define other methods and classes here
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError := True)> _
Public Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
End Function

Public Shared Function GetProcess(hwnd As IntPtr) As Process
    Dim intID As Integer = 0
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, intID)
    Return Process.GetProcessById(intID)
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError := True)> _
Public Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Public Shared Function GetShortEXEName(hwnd As IntPtr) As String
    ' this seems to be better to use than calling GetProcessEXEName and then using substring functions to get the short executable name
    ' because that function seems to crash when dealing with Windows Explorer windows
    Try
        Return GetProcess(hwnd).ProcessName
    Catch
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```